# 405: Method not allowed error,nodeJS

Tags: node.js, http-post

I have exposed some apis in nodeJs
I am able to perform GET requests, but when I try Post request I am getting following errors

```
405: Method not allowed error
{
"code": "MethodNotAllowedError"
"message": "POST is not allowed"
}
```

Other than this I am not able to get any information about error. I tried lots of things like below but none of them working..

```
global.restify = require('restify');
global.appRoot = path.resolve(__dirname);
global.app = restify.createServer({name:'test'});
    app.opts(/.*/, function (req,res,next) {

      //  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", req.header("Access-Control-Request-Method"));
      //  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", req.header("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
    //    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

      //res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
      //res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");

      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
          res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
      res.send(200);

        //res.send(200);
        return next();
    });
```

Comment: What is `app.opts()`? What web framework are you using on the server?

Comment: Its restify framework

Comment: Can you also show the route you're trying to POST to? Aside from that (I don't think it's related): I'm not overly familiar with Restify, but is `res.send(200)` something that works in middleware that it supposed to pass requests on to other handlers?

Comment: Share the handlers in restify for post requests.
Are you making cross origin request, which means nodejs sever and front-end site are on different domains.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you already have defined a handler for your `POST`requests.

Judging from your code, I suppose you want to support CORS. The proper way to do that in restify [would be](http://restify.com/#bundled-plugins):

```js
server.use(restify.CORS());
```

or

```js
server.use(restify.CORS({
    origins: ['https://foo.com', 'http://bar.com', 'http://baz.com:8081'],   // defaults to ['*']
    credentials: true,                 // defaults to false
    headers: ['x-foo']                 // sets expose-headers
}));
```

**Side node**: `send` sets headers, and ends the response!